# Electron mkdirSync EACCES on MAC

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I would like create a new folder in user data path on MAC, but i've a EACCES problem on MAC only.

I want create `data` folder in `electron.app.getPath('userData')` :

`fs.mkdirSync(electron.app.getPath('userData'))`

Anyone know how i can create new folder in App path ?

Thank you community :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the node path library to add the name of the folder you want to create to the queries path.

```
newPath = path.join(appPath, ‘myNewFolder’)
fs.mkdirSync(newPath)
```